# Can I get invoice reference number after calling "Prepare Invoice" action from "Actions" menu through web API?

Tags: acumatica

I was trying to use web API to prepare invoice by calling "Prepare Invoice" from the top "Actions" menu on Sales Order screen SO301000 and then release this invoice on Invoice SO303000, however, after the invoice was prepared successfully I need to know the invoice reference number in order to release this invoice but I couldn't find a way to get this reference no or verify whether the action was successful or not from the return information. My code is below:

```
            SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
            context.SO301000Clear();

            SO301000.Actions.PrepareInvoiceAction.Commit = true;

            List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = soType, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = soNbr, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = customerCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer, Commit = true });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = customerLocation, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Location});

            cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.PrepareInvoiceAction);
            cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);

            SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());

            //Check whether invoice is successfully prepared and return reference No if it's successful. 
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            List<InvoiceInfo> InvoiceList = this.GetInvoiceInfoBySO(soNbr);
            if (InvoiceList.Count > 0)
            {
                //successful
            }
            else
            {
                .....//failed
            }
```

Anybody knows how to verify whether the action is successful or not and preferably get invoice reference number somehow?

For now I called an generic inquiry to get invoice reference number based on SO order no, it somewhat worked - that is going to be my another question ( it worked only when I put some sleep in the code otherwise I still couldn't get that new reference number - it seems there is a bug that causes some kind delay), but I will create another question for it.

Thanks.

Update: Sorry, I copied the wrong code and now it has been updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,

so after you submit the commands, you can do the following to check whether the processing has finished or not.

SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());

```
var status = context.SO301000GetProcessStatus();
                            while (status.Status == ProcessStatus.InProcess)
                            {
                                status = context.SO301000GetProcessStatus();
                            }
```

For getting the prepared invoice number, what i did was, i tried getting the sales order document back and read the invoice number from the shipments tab.

Comment: Thanks! The code worked and it's much better than "sleep()".